# Show that given $N$ iid variates $X_i$ uniform on (0,1), $P(\max(\{x_i\} > \frac{1}{2}\sum x_i)$ is $\frac{1}{( N-1)!}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given an ensemble of $N$ random uniform variates on $(0,1)$, the probability that the greatest variate exceeds the sum of all the other variates is $\frac{1}{(N-1)!}$.

Is there any nice way to prove it by some geometric or combinatoric argument?

Comment: You can relate such probability with the measure of a pyramid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_j$ be independent uniform random variables on $(0,1)$.  Conditioned on $\max(X_1, \ldots, X_N) = X_m$, the other $X_j$ are independent uniform on $(0, X_m)$.   Thus your probability is the probability that the sum of $N-1$ independent uniform(0,1) random variables is less than 1.  The region
$A = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_{N-1}) \in \mathbb R^{N-1}: x_1 + \ldots + x_{N-1} \le 1\}$ is a simplex with vertices $0$ and $e_j$ (the standard unit vectors).
But you'll find the answer is $1/(N-1)!$, not $1/(2 N!)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks; I had the answer wrong.  The 2 came from idiotically starting from $P_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ where it is obviously $1$.  The $N!$ instead of $(N-1)!$ was just carelessness -- I used induction to show the result for $N+!$ from the result for $N$, so I was quoting $P_{N+1}$ and saying it is the prob for $N$.